# How to replace an image when accessing it by url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

**Prehistory**

The site has a logo in the header of the site. The image of the logo is png with a transparent background and the effect of indentation (which means that there is a border around the elements of the logo).
Example (from the Internet): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eJFJ.jpg)
Often the logo is opened through the context menu (the right button of the mouse - Open image) and is used for posting on sites, and even in print products (instead of requesting a logo from us). Unfortunately, there are more and more links in the network (partners and journalists), and therefore it is problematic to track everything.

**Question**

Is it possible to replace the logo image with direct access to it via url (site.com/logo.png) to another url, for example on site.com/logo-print.png?
There are other problems: "Copy image", "Copy link to image", but they are secondary.

*The search did not lead to anything. I suspect that I'm looking in the wrong direction at all. All that came to my mind is the replacement of the context menu on the element. But while this solution looks a little cumbersome for a seemingly simple task.*

Comment: Why don't you just make a "Press" section and offer a package for journalists and partners with high-res versions of your logo, together with a style guide? For example, [Ruger](https://www.ruger.com/resources/index.html) offers high-res versions of their logo together with a styleguide.

Comment: As David states you could make a press-kit for your partners. CSS and media queries can be used to show different sizes, display (lo-res) and print (a high-res version). There is no way to prevent anyone from grabbing the logo once it's being displayed (screengrab)...